# "Ich mag ihn nicht" and expressing mild dislike of something

Tags: meaning

I was taught that **mögen** with a direct object corresponds to *don't like* or *don't care for* in English, and I've used expressions such as **Ich mag ihn nicht** to mean a general but not especially strong dislike: *I don't care much for him*.

Recently I was corrected by a German-speaking friend who said the sentence **Ich mag ihn nicht** is actually very strong, and corresponds better to *I really don't like him at all* or even *I can't stand him.*

In German, how would you express mild dislike for something, such as *I don't care much for that author* or *I'm not a big fan of that restaurant*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## `nicht mögen`

Given the sentence *I don't care much for that author* you can absolutely use ***nicht mögen***.

> Ich mag diesen Autor nicht [so [sehr]].
>   Shakespeare mag ich nicht [so [sehr]].
>
> Das Restaurant mag ich nicht [so [sehr]].

You can weaken your dislike adding *so / so sehr*. Anyway, this expresses a dislike rather towards the author's works, except the context indicates something different.

## `nicht leiden können / nicht leiden mögen / nicht abkönnen`

> Shakespeare kann ich nicht [so [sehr]] leiden.
>   Tomaten mag ich nicht [so [sehr]] leiden.
>   Hochmut kann ich nicht ab.

Also note, that it's always important *how* you say it.

## `nicht gefallen`

It's similar with ***nicht gefallen***, but you'd use that not when referring to a person, unless you want to say, that a person does not appeal to you (as in his outer appearance).

> Mir gefallen die Sachen/Werke/Bücher/Texte dieses Autor nicht [so [sehr]].
>   Die Sachen/Werke/Bücher/Texte von Shakespeare gefallen mir nicht [so [sehr]].
>
> Das Restaurant gefällt mir nicht [so [sehr]].

## `nicht gut finden`

Another option is e. g. ***nicht gut finden***

> Ich finde diesen Autor nicht [so] gut.
>   Shakespeare finde ich weniger gut.  *(When talking about some authors)*
>   Das Restaurant finde ich schlecht.

Mind that ***schlecht*** is relatively strong (if you say it in a serious way).

## `eher nicht ...`

In any of the upper given cases you can use ***eher nicht*** instead of ***nicht*** to weaken the negative statement.

> Das Restaurant mag ich eher nicht.
>   Die Sachen/Werke/Bücher/Texte von Shakespeare gefallen mir eher nicht so.
>   Ich finde diesen Autor eher nicht so gut.

## Further expressions

There are other, more specific expressions which depend on what you're talking about. For instance ***nicht ansprechen***, ***nicht schmecken***, ***nichts finden an***, ...

> Die Sachen/Werke/Bücher/Texte von Shakespeare sprechen mich nicht [so [sehr]] an.
>   [Das Essen] In diesem Restaurant schmeckt [mir] nicht [so [sehr]].
>   Ich finde an Kinogängen nichts [Gutes / Interessantes / Vorteilhaftes / Ansprechendes / ...].

---

If you use ***mögen*** referring to a private person, it will/can e. g. express negative, unpleasant feelings connected with the presence of this person.

Comment: Maybe you want to add "jmdn. (nicht) leiden können" to your list.

Comment: @raphael You'd consider it a *mild* dislike when somebody says that to you or if somebody says so, referring to an action or object?

Comment: I think it'd come in at about the same as "nicht mögen" and can be weakened in just the same way.

Answer (score 9):

> Recently I was corrected by a German-speaking friend who said the sentence Ich mag ihn nicht is actually very strong, and corresponds better to I really don't like him at all or even I can't stand him.

I don't think it's *very* strong, but, yes, it expresses dislike, pretty much the way "I don't like him" does in English.

> In German, how would you express mild dislike for something, such as I don't care much for that author or I'm not a big fan of that restaurant?

Try adding another word: Ich mag ihn nicht **sehr**. Ich mag ihn nicht **besonders**.

If, on the other hand, you want a stronger expression you can use *überhaupt nicht* (not at all).

Answer (score 6):

Here are some more alternatives for expressing a weak dislike:

#### Gleichgültig sein

This closely matches *don't care* as it says you have no feelings for somebody. *Gleichgültig* only indirectly implies negative feelings by negating any interest for somebody. It can not be used for objects.

> Peter ist mir gleichgültig.

This can further be weakened by adding *fast schon*, or made stronger by adding *ziemlich, völlig, ...*.

#### Nicht mein Fall sein

By stating that something/somebody is *nicht mein Fall* we just express that we are not very fond of it/him/her. Again a dislike is only indirectly implied, and it is not very strong.

> Peter ist nicht mein Fall. Rohes Fleisch ist nicht mein Fall. Der Film gestern war nicht mein Fall.

#### Express your dislike by being specific, using *ist (mir) zu*

Especially with people, but is also works with objects we quite often say specifically what we do not like. This will then also be weaker as a general expression of dislike. This however is not specific to German but a matter of style, really.

> Peter ist mir zu laut. Das Restaurant war zu voll. Das Essen ist mir zu scharf. Der Film war zu lang.

Comment: **Nicht mein Fall** is a great expression.  I'm tempted to translate it into English as _not my cup of tea_ or _not my thing_, but those are pretty slangy and colloquial, and they'd be very strange in formal writing.  Is **nicht mein Fall** used in formal writing or in more elevated registers?

Comment: @DanLeifker: you can use it in writing too (but the more formal it is the more you may want to be specific).