# „jmd. sehr mögen“ vs „jmd. gern leiden mögen"

Tags: verb-usage, modal-verb

To express that I like someone, it seems that I can use both “*jmd. mögen*” and “*jmd. gern leiden mögen*”.  i.e.

*1. Ich mag sie sehr.*

*2. Ich mag sie gern leiden.*

Could someone please advise on when the “*gern leiden mögen*” form would be used?

There are two StackExchange posts [here](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/48854/leiden-k%C3%B6nnen-nicht-leiden-k%C3%B6nnen-ist-ein-problem-f%C3%BCr-mich-do-i-get-the-mea/48855#48855) and [here](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/12396/ich-mag-ihn-nicht-and-expressing-mild-dislike-of-something/12397#12397) that do talk about *leiden können* and *nicht leiden mögen*, but it is not clear to me when to use the form with *leiden*.

Comment: I have corrected the word order of the infinitives, because that seemed to be irrelevant to your question.

Comment: Thank you, I am still getting used to the order of multiple infinitives. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO is "**ich mag sie (sehr) leiden**" outdated. I didn't heard it in normal conversations for decades.

"**Ich mag sie sehr**" or "**ich mag sie gern**" is still used.